# Characters not being set correctly in Two-Dimensional Char Array

Tags: c++, arrays

I was playing around and I created two dimensional char array. Now I'm having problems, when I try to put characters in that array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char field[8][8];

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
    {
    if(field[i][j]==field[2][6])
    {
    field[i][j]='X';
    }
    else
    {
    field[i][j]='-';    
    }
    cout<<field[i][j];  
    }
    cout<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

But this gives me:

[image: cmd]

I only want `X` to be at `field[2][6]` and not from `field[2][0]` to `field[2][6]`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(field[i][j]==field[2][6])` is checking if the contents of `field[i][j]` are the same as `field[2][6]`.  It is not checking the position.  If you only want `field[2][6]` to have then `X` then you can use

```
if (i == 2 && j == 6)
{
    field[i][j]='X';
}
else
{
    field[i][j]='-';    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare i and j not array[i][j] so,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char field[8][8];

    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j<8; j++)
        {
            if (i ==2 && j==6)
            {
                field[i][j] = 'X';
            }
            else
            {
                field[i][j] = '-';
            }
            cout << field[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    system("pause>null");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yea ty I know it now :D

Comment: OK so at least you can give my answer a score :)